# How to initialize audio with Vala/SDL

Tags: audio, sdl, vala

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now.

In order to start up the audio, I need to create an SDL.AudioSpec object and pass it to SDL.Audio.Open.  The problem is, AudioSpec is a class with a private constructor, so when I try to create one I get:

```
sdl.vala:18.25-18.43: error: `SDL.AudioSpec' does not have a default constructor
        AudioSpec audiospec = new SDL.AudioSpec();
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And if I try to just assign values to it's member vars like a struct (it's a struct in normal sdl) I get:

```
sdl.vala:20.3-20.25: error: use of possibly unassigned local variable `audiospec'
        audiospec.freq = 22050;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I found the valac doc here: http://valadoc.org/sdl/SDL.AudioSpec.html
But it isn't much help at all.

The offending code block looks like this:

```
// setup the audio configuration
AudioSpec audiospec;
AudioSpec specback;
audiospec.freq = 22050;
audiospec.format = SDL.AudioFormat.S16LSB;
audiospec.channels = 2;
audiospec.samples = 512;

// try to initialize sound with these values
if (SDL.Audio.open(audiospec, specback) < 0)
{
    stdout.printf("ERROR! Check audio settings!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Another update, as I'm still having some trouble.  I've changed the vapi file, and this is what I have now:

```
public delegate void AudioCallback (out void* userdata, out uchar stream, int len);

[CCode (cname="SDL_AudioSpec")]
[Compact]
public struct AudioSpec {
    public int freq;
    public AudioFormat format;
    public uchar channels;
    public uchar silence;
    public uint16 samples;
    public uint16 padding;
    public uint32 size;
    public AudioCallback callback;
    public void* userdata;
}// AudioSpec
```

I have a method that (tries?) to meet this function signature:

```
public void callback(out void* userdata, out uchar stream, int len)
{
    stream = 0;
    userdata = null;
}
```

And assigning it as:

```
    audiospec.callback = gen.callback;
```

Needless to say, this still isn't working, get lots of errors:

```
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c: In function ‘sound_gen_main’:
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c:766:12: error: ‘SDL_AudioSpec’ has no member named ‘callback_target_destroy_notify’
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c:766:72: error: ‘SDL_AudioSpec’ has no member named ‘callback_target_destroy_notify’
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c:766:114: error: ‘SDL_AudioSpec’ has no member named ‘callback_target’
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c:768:11: error: ‘SDL_AudioSpec’ has no member named ‘callback_target’
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c:769:11: error: ‘SDL_AudioSpec’ has no member named ‘callback_target_destroy_notify’
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c:770:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c:771:11: error: ‘SDL_AudioSpec’ has no member named ‘callback_target’
/home/gukid/vala/soundgen.vala.c:772:11: error: ‘SDL_AudioSpec’ has no member named ‘callback_target_destroy_notify’
error: cc exited with status 256
```

So I'm at a bit of another sticky point.

3rd post:  EUREKA!  I have a solution! (debatable :P)

First off, the sdl.vapi looks like:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "SDL.h")]
public delegate void AudioCallback (void* userdata, uchar* stream, int len);

[CCode (cname="SDL_AudioSpec", has_type_id=false)]
public struct AudioSpec {
    public int freq;
    public AudioFormat format;
    public uchar channels;
    public uchar silence;
    public uint16 samples;
    public uint16 padding;
    public uint32 size;
    [CCode (delegate_target = false, type = "void*")]
    public weak AudioCallback callback;
    public void* userdata;
}// AudioSpec
```

And then I can just create a function:

```
public static void callback(void* userdata, uchar* stream, int len)
```

And:

```
audiospec.callback = callback;
```

Ahhh, finally my beautiful white noise generator is complete!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug in the VAPI. In sdl.vapi, try changing

```
[Compact]
public class AudioSpec {
```

to

```
public struct AudioSpec {
```

and

```
[CCode (cname="SDL_OpenAudio")]
public static int open(AudioSpec desired, AudioSpec obtained);
```

to

```
[CCode (cname="SDL_OpenAudio")]
public static int open(AudioSpec desired, out AudioSpec obtained);
```

and make your code look like:

```
AudioSpec audiospec = AudioSpec();
AudioSpec specback;
audiospec.freq = 22050;
audiospec.format = SDL.AudioFormat.S16LSB;
audiospec.channels = 2;
audiospec.samples = 512;

// try to initialize sound with these values
if (SDL.Audio.open(audiospec, out specback) < 0)
{
    stdout.printf("ERROR! Check audio settings!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

and give it a test. It seems to generate the correct code according to the SDL docs. If it works, consider submitting the VAPI changes to the Vala bugzilla.

Comment: That worked great for getting it to compile!  I'm still not able to get the sound to open though, and I'm thinking it might have something to do with the enum not having a callback pointer.  In the original sdl:

typedef struct ...
  void (*callback)(void *userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len);

I'll see if I can find a way to add it into sdl.vapi.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the delegate:

```
public delegate void AudioCallback (out void* userdata, out uchar stream, int len);
```

has the C type:

```
void(*AudioCallback)(void**userdata, unsigned char* stream, int len);
```

where userdata and stream are write-only, which is not really what you want.

```
void (*callback)(void *userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len);
```

In this, `userdata` is just a pointer to some stuff for your use. In Vala's terms, it's the target of a delegate. `stream` is an array, but SDL has allocated it, so it's not `out` and `len` is the length of the array, so we can have Vala deal with that automatically with just `uint8[] stream`. Putting it all together:

```
[CCode(instance_pos = 0)]
public delegate void AudioCallback(uint8[] stream);
```

The `instance_pos` tells Vala where the userdata is. It normally assumes it to be last. As for the struct:

```
[CCode (cname="SDL_AudioSpec", destroy_function = "")]
public struct AudioSpec {
  ...
  [CCode(delegate_target_cname = "userdata")]
  public AudioCallback callback;
}
```

This will create a callback that stores the target in `userdata`. Now, to avoid leaking memory, Vala is going to try to assign a destructor to `callback_target_destroy_notify`...and now we're stuck because we have no member for that. So, let's back up and try again:

```
[CCode(has_target = false)]
public delegate void AudioCallback(void* userdata, uint8[] stream);
```

The `has_target` tells Vala there is no userdata and we include it manually. As for the struct:

```
[CCode (cname="SDL_AudioSpec", destroy_function = "")]
public struct AudioSpec {
  ...
  public AudioCallback callback;
  public void* userdata;
}
```

So, userdata will get passed to your callback, but you'll have to cast it yourself and you'll have to manage the memory. Additionally, when the structs go out of scope, Vala is going to call a destroy function. By specifying an empty string, it will do nothing. Normally, this frees memory inside the struct, but we don't need to worry here.

Comment: Thank you for all the info!  I've actually done a bit of research, and have come up with a solution as well, that compiles and gives me some noise.  It more than likely memory leaks or something (my solution) but I'm not worried about that for now.  Again, thanks for all your help, would have never figured this out on my own!